# Сборка проекта на Ассемблер под Windows x64 в Visual Studio 2020

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, x86-64

Дано задание посчитать выражение: X = (A * 2 + B * C) / (D – 3 ).

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
        a db ?
        b db ?
        c db ? ;Резерв памяти для
        d db ? ;A,B,C,D,X
        x dw ?
.code
    start:
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        mov a,3
        mov b,4
        mov c,2
        mov d,5
        mov al,2
        mul a
        mov cx,ax
        mov al,b
        mul c
        add ax,cx
        mov cl,d
        sub cl,3
        div cl
        mov x,ax
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
end start
```

При сборке выводит кучу ошибок[image: errors]

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем причина и как это исправить.
P.S. Проект собираю в Visual studio 2019 под х64.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=msvc-160